# State of child when parent calls useState update function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Suppose I have the following code snippet (Please consider it as a pseudo code)

Parent.js

```
const [state,action]=useState(0);
return <View><Child1/><Button onPress={()=>action(1)}/></View>
```

Child1.js

```
const [state]=useState(Math.random());
return <Text>{state}</Text>
```

So my question is when I click the button in the parent will the Chil1 state change or not.
On my local machine it seems it changes.

Comment: it doesn't change any way

Comment: So you mean to say, that state of the child is preserved when changing the state of the parent (ofcourse both states are independent) ?

Comment: Since the state of child is default value, so even the parent update many times, it won't be changed unless you remove it and then you re-render it!

Comment: But doesn't changing parent state re-render all of it's child elements ?

Comment: I will show you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of `useState` is that once a component is mounted, the state value does not change across re-renders until the update state function is called, passing a new state value.

Therefore, even though your parent component Button press state change triggers a rerender of the child, since the child component is only being rerendered and not unmounted/remounted, the initial state of `Math.random()` would remain the same.

See [useState in React: A complete guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/)

Comment: Well this makes sense, on why the value of child is changing ( I am receiving the  Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component). May be this error is the reason the value is being getting updated. Any pointers on this ?

Comment: I would surmise that there is more happening in the code than what you have shared - you must be inadvertently unmounting components unnecessarily somewhere....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exact scenario is, but if you just set default `state`, the `state` will be memorized like Scenario 1

**Scenario 1**

In this way, the `state` of `Child` will not be changed even if `Parent` re-render

```js
const Child = () => {
  const [state] = useState(Math.random());
  return <div>{state}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [, action] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => action(false)}>Not Change</button>
      <Child />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Scenario 2**

Unless you remove it and then re-render `Parent` even if memorize all `Child`, that is

```js
const Child = () => {
  const [state] = useState(Math.random());
  return <div>{state}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, action] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) action(true)
  }, [state])

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => action(false)}>Change</button>
      {state && <Child />}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Scenario 3**

By the may, if you don't use default `state`, in this way, it will be changed every rendering like that

```
const Child = () => {
  return <div>{Math.random()}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [, action] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => action(prev => !prev)}>Change</button>
      <Child />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Scenario 4**

If we don't want `Child` to re-render, we can try [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memorize it

```
const Child = memo(() => {
  return <div>{Math.random()}</div>
})
```

**Scenario 5**

However, when `Child` has props, perhaps we should invole [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to make sure the values or memory addresses of props are "fixed" like constant, so that `Child` won't re-render

(*We don't have to use `useCallback` or `useMemo` all the time, it doesn't much matter when there is no performance problem*)

```
const Child = memo((props) => {
  return <div {...props}>{Math.random()}</div>
})

const Parent = () => {
  const [, action] = useState(true);
  const style = useMemo(() => ({}), [])
  const onOK = useCallback(() => alert(1), [])
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => action(prev => !prev)}>Change</button>
      <Child className="test" style={style} onClick={onOK} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. What is the difference between Scenario 1,2 that makes the child lost its state

Comment: My pleasure, it didn't take much time.

Comment: I have one additional question: I am receiving the error that cannot update an unmounted element. Do you have any pointers on that ?

Comment: Show your code in codesandbox plz, or Idk what  issue is exactly.

Comment: When click button, the scenario 1 will only re-render once, and the scenario 2 re-render twice, in which one render `<Child />` was removed from `<Parent />`, i.e. the component was unmounted, so its default `state` didn't work, and in another re-render, `<Child />` got back.